# c# winform use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have code that retrieve the value in the database as prev_count and do some calculation:

```
public void calc(string query1,int total_pages1,string m,int y)
    {
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query1, connection);
            MySqlDataReader datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int calc_pages;
            int prev_count;
            while (datareader.Read())
            {
                prev_count = datareader.GetInt32(0);
                calc_pages = total_pages1 - prev_count;
            }
            //close Data Reader
                datareader.Close();

            Insert(m, y, calc_pages); // problem line

            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is that, the error state that "use of unassigned local variable 'calc_pages' ". I know this is a simple, but im new to c#. Help anyone?

Comment: Just a quick nit-pick (nothing serious), you are using `Ruby` style notation with your variables, in C# the vastly accepted format is `likeThis` rather than `like_this`.  Obviously this has no bearing on your code or question specifically, just makes it more inline with c# practices.

Comment: @EvanL noted,maybe I get use of php and merge it to c#. Need to improve my practices.TQ

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot about PHP, same notation as Ruby typically.  No worries, just a tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to assign a value to `calc_pages` before using it. So, instead of this:

```
int calc_pages;
int prev_count;
```

You should be doing this:

```
int calc_pages = 0;
int prev_count = 0;
```

Comment: Just to follow up as to *why* it is happening, if the `datareader.Read()` method returns false, the while loop is never entered. When execution hits `Insert(m, y, calc_pages)` `calc_pages` is not initialized, which is what the error was telling you about.

Comment: @Joshua yaa this logic explain everything. so need to assign the value before entering the while loop and it works.thanks

Answer (score 2):

It *appears* you're assigning a value to `calc_pages` before referencing it later.

The problem is, if there's no data in the `datareader`, then the `while` loop will not run, and the values will never be assigned a value.

The compiler can't determine ahead of time whether or not the loop will execute, so you get an error.

*(You'd currently get the same error if you tried to use* `prev_count` *outside the* `while` *loop.)*